# Can WMTS URL placeholders be used in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers, wmts

In OpenLayers 2 I am using WMTS with following URL (basemap.at):

```
https://maps.wien.gv.at/basemap/geolandbasemap/{Style}/{TileMatrixSet}/{TileMatrix}/{TileRow}/{TileCol}.png
```

Is that possible in OpenLayers 3 too?

Comment: OK, I found the solution. I forgot to set "requestEncoding" to REST, so it took "KVP" as default

Comment: Please add this finding as answer to your own question, maybe with a relevant code snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My Layer looks like this:

```
new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.WMTS({
                    url: 'https://maps.wien.gv.at/basemap/geolandbasemap/{Style}/{TileMatrixSet}/{TileMatrix}/{TileRow}/{TileCol}.png',
                    layer: 'geolandbasemap',
                    matrixSet: 'google3857',
                    format: 'image/png',
                    projection: 'google3857',
                    requestEncoding: "REST",
                    tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.WMTS({
                        origin: [-20037508.3428, 20037508.3428],
                        resolutions: [156543.03392811998, 78271.51696419998, 39135.758481959994, 19567.879241008, 9783.939620504, 4891.969810252, 2445.984905126, 1222.9924525644, 611.4962262807999, 305.74811314039994, 152.87405657047998, 76.43702828523999, 38.21851414248, 19.109257071295996, 9.554628535647998, 4.777314267823999, 2.3886571339119995, 1.1943285669559998, 0.5971642834779999, 0.2985821417404, 0.1, 0.05],
                        matrixIds:["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21"],
                        minZoom: 0,
                        maxZoom: 20,
                    }),
                    style: 'normal'

                })
            })
```

The problem was that I did not set the 'requestEncoding' property, so the defaualt 'KVP' was used. Thereby the placeholders were not replaced.